# How to check if NotifyIcon is hidden

Tags: c#, .net, windows, system-tray, trayicon

I don't want to FORCE it to be visible, I just want it to check to see if it is hidden by Windows.

Windows by default, hides the trayicons other than the system icons (Action Center, Battery, Network, Sound, Date and Time).

[image]

Comment: There is no way to find out, by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hans says there's no direct way to find out, which is unfortunate (but makes sense).

You can still try to find out indirectly. You can [take a snapshot of the desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292700/efficiently-acquiring-a-screenshot-of-the-windows-desktop) bitmap, find the task-bar (I think that in Windows 7 it can't be moved from the bottom, I'm not sure) and look for your icon. If you find it - it's there.

Comment: The taskbar can be moved to any edge of the screen in W7.

Comment: I couldn't move it. Anyway, OP will have to look for it in all possible positions. And remember that in RTL OSes, the icons may appear on the left.

Comment: You'll have to unlock it first. Right click -> Lock the taskbar

Comment: If I was to do this it would have to be legitimately... This is not necessary for me but it would be useful. :)

Comment: What is illegitimate about this approach? Besides being error-prone (which is legitimate if you handle it properly...)

Answer (score 2):

I use the function [Shell_NotifyIconGetRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicongetrect), and get return value to check if NotifyIcon is hidden.

When the `NotifyIcon` is not hidden (in visible Tray part) , the function will return zero. When the `NotifyIcon` is hidden, the function will return 0x00000001 that means `Incorrect function`. It is really hack, and I don't know why. here is an example:

```
bool isIconHidden = false;
int hresult = Shell_NotifyIconGetRect(ref nid, out rect);

if (hresult == 0)
{
    isIconHidden = false;
}
else if (hresult == 0x00000001)
{
    isIconHidden = true;
}
else
    throw new Win32Exception(hresult);
```

The more detail about Shell_NotifyIconGetRect function usage, please see [Notify Icon Position](https://www.quppa.net/blog/2010/12/08/windows-7-style-notification-area-applications-in-wpf-part-2-notify-icon-position/) and [Determining location of tray icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366449/determining-location-of-tray-icon).
But I'm not sure the solution is available on all Windows platforms. My OS is Win10
Family. hope it works for you.