# WPF applications tray icon

Tags: c#, wpf, tray

I am developing WPF application and need to create popup like in Skype - when you click on tray icon it appears with centric horizontal alignment in relation to the icon (like in attached image). Do you know how to do this? Please, help.
[Skype example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4wdb.png)

Comment: Show the work you've done so far

Comment: Look on the https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon - you may implement your notification using this framework.

Comment: @developer_117 i used library wpf-notifyicon by hardcodet [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon) , but horizontal alignment is not as i want. skype variant is exactly what i want.

Comment: @VitaliyK, thank you, I already use this library, but horizontal alignment is not as i want. Maybe you know how to make popup with centric horizontal alignment in relation to the icon.

Comment: The horizontal alignment is a part of implementation - I guess you will need to get a position of your tray icon in a tray(for ex as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366449/determining-location-of-tray-icon) and than calculate your alignment relatively to this coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx) to show notification balloon.

```
var notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
    {
        Visible = true,
        Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
        Text = Title
    };

    notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1, "Hello World", "Description message", System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info);
```